# Selecting changed rows from an audit table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an audit table which logs when a user changes a nominal code for a parts list.

As you can see the first column is the part, the second column is the date changed and the third is a nominal code.
This is just a sample of the data, the table actually has a huge amount of rows.

I want to bring back only those parts where the nominal code has changed, showing what it was originally and what it is now.
Basically there was a bug where a process kept changing the code, so I need to know what it was before.

```
| PART       | DATE CHANG | Nominal code
|------------|------------|-------
| ENGINEWORK | 05/08/2014 | 4000 |
| ENGINEWORK | 06/08/2014 | 4007 |
| ENGINEWORK | 04/09/2014 | 4007 |
| ENGINEWORK | 05/09/2014 | 4007 |
| ENGINEWORK | 15/09/2014 | 4007 |
| ENGINEWORK | 25/09/2014 | 4007 |
| HYPOIDOIL  | 05/08/2014 | 4005 |
| HYPOIDOIL  | 07/08/2014 | 4005 |
| HYPOIDOIL  | 08/08/2014 | 4000 |
| HYPOIDOIL  | 14/08/2014 | 4000 |
| LLB382     | 05/08/2014 | 5000 |
| LLB382     | 07/08/2014 | 4000 |
| LLB382     | 07/08/2014 | 5000 |
| LLB382     | 08/08/2014 | 4000 |
| LLB382     | 14/08/2014 | 4000 |
| LLB382     | 20/10/2014 | 4000 |
```

Comment: Sorry note managed to format the table.....give me a minute

Comment: I tried:
'select part, min(auditdate),max(auditdate), sales_gl_code
from _Parts_Audit
where part in (select part from _Parts_Audit where sales_gl_code != '4000')
group by part,  sales_gl_code''

Im not sure if its right or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your desired result set shows each time the part number changes. This query will find every time the code changes value for a part and the date in which that event occurred.

```
    with rankedResult
    as (
        select t.*,
            row_number() over (
                partition by part order by dateChanged
                ) as seqnum
        from Audit t
        )
    select t.part,
        t.code CurrentCode,
        t2.code ChangedToCode,
        t2.dateChanged ChangedDate
    from rankedResult t
    inner join rankedResult t2 on t.part = t2.part
        and t.seqnum = t2.seqnum + 1
        and t.code != t2.code;
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want the first and last values for the code.  I would suggest window functions:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by part order by datechange) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by part) as cnt
      from audit t
     )
select part,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then nominalcode end) as firstcode,
       max(case when seqnum = cnt then nominalcode end) as lastcode
from t
group by part
having max(case when seqnum = 1 then nominalcode end) <> max(case when seqnum = cnt then nominalcode end);
```

Comment: Thank you for that, although i get a 'Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.' when I run it, all I have changed is the column names in the query.